# How can I get this to not mix up the new word and the category

Tags: python, chatbot

`This is really long, but I can't ask without context (I am a beginner, so this is just a test to see if I could make some grammar rules in code, I'm sorry about the spaghetti)

Whenever I run this through my ide and try to teach it a new word it just returns the name of the category where I put the new word

```py
greetings = ["hello","hi","yo","wassup","hey"]
possesive = ["my","mine","your","yours","our","ours","their","theirs"]
names = ["john","michael","jim","bill","bob","amy","jessica","holly","olivia","sophia"]
isverbs = ["is","was","are","were","will","be","become"]
doverbs = ["walk","run","jog","drive","shop","write","read","watch","listen","can","will","won't","can't"]
feelingverbs = ["like","dislike","hate","want","wish","dread","enjoy"]
adjectives = ["big","small","fast","slow","strong","weak","great","terrible","honest","better"]
nouns = ["name","bike","hand","hands","leg","legs","car","eye","eyes","names","cars","bikes","computer","computers"]
pronouns = ["i","me","you","he","him","she","her","us","we","them","they"]
conjunctions = ["and","or","but","however"]
prepositions = ["in","at","of","to","on"]
formnums = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11']
allforms = [greetings,possesive,names,isverbs,doverbs,feelingverbs,adjectives,nouns,pronouns,conjunctions,prepositions]
allnames = ["greetings","posessive","names","isverbs","doverbs","feelingverbs","adjectives","nouns","pronouns","conjunctions","prepositions"]
formdictionary = dict(zip(formnums,allnames))


def converttowords(rawsentence):
  sentence = rawsentence.split()
  wordnum = len(sentence)
  for words in sentence:
    print(words)
  return sentence

def newwords(unknownword):
  print("I do not know the word", unknownword, ", please pick which category to place it   ")
  whereappend = input(formdictionary)
  whereappendnum = int(whereappend)
  whereappendnum -= 1
  allforms[whereappendnum].append(unknownword)
  return allforms[whereappendnum]

def getmeaning(sentence):
  wordnum = 0
  wrong = "this is wrong"
  for x in sentence:
    if(x in greetings):
      sentence[wordnum] = "greeting"
    elif(x in possesive):
      sentence[wordnum] = "possesive"
    elif(x in names):
      sentence[wordnum] = "name"
    elif(x in isverbs):
      sentence[wordnum] = "is verb"
    elif(x in doverbs):
      sentence[wordnum] = "do verb"
    elif(x in feelingverbs):
      sentence[wordnum] = "feeling verb"
    elif(x in adjectives):
      sentence[wordnum] = "adjective"
    elif(x in nouns):
      sentence[wordnum] = "noun"
    elif(x in pronouns ):
      sentence[wordnum] = "pronoun"
    elif(x in conjunctions):
      sentence[wordnum] = "conjunction"
    elif(x in prepositions):
      sentence[wordnum] = "preposition"
    else:
      unknownword = x
      return unknownword
    wordnum += 1
  wordnum = 0  
  for word in sentence:
    print(sentence[wordnum])
    wordnum += 1
  return sentence

a = 9
while a == 9:
  inpt = input("Say a sentence!    ")
  if(getmeaning(converttowords(inpt)) not in allforms):
    newwords(getmeaning(converttowords(inpt)))
```

(ps: I spelled possessive wrong)

I tried to fix it by various different ways of calling the newword() function, and thought that that would make it return the new word, but it didn't, it just kept on returning the name of the category.`